# Extract a specific string from within specific tags via regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long file which contains lots of strings like:

```
<s>@</s><b>username</b>
```

I need to extract all usernames from this long file and would like to do that with Notepad++ regex, but I have no clue how to.

Any tips?

Comment: Parsing XML with regex is often a bad idea. Expect problems or start using an XML library.

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Is this file in XML/HTML format, or is it literally as you describe i.e. in a fixed format?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace everything which are between `</b>` or `^` and `<b>` with `\n` so that only usernames will be left.

So replace `(<\/b>|^).+?(<b>|$)` with `\n`.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/zI7gJ1/1